# Using functionality stored in a partial class elsewhere

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, partial-classes

I am new to programming so please be kind. Visual studio automates some source code for you like when adding a database. Dbcontext has some virtual function that can be overwritten such as savechanges. I have several different classes that extend Dbcontext, all partial classes. How would I implement the same functionality across these different entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend DbContext to create a new abstract class, and then change your existing partial classes to extend from that new class.